# Pass values from openjscad to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, openjscad

is it possible to pass a value from openjscad to javascript?

I would like to show the dimensions of a 3d-object in a div or any other html-element.

Example:
A cube is created with openjscad with the following parameters:

```
function main() {
    var cube = CSG.cube({
        center: [0, 0, 0],
        radius: [1, 2, 3]
    });
    return cube;
}
```

How can I pass the parameters for `center` and `radius` to javascript in order to use them in other areas of the website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this by making my own cube object, you can add all the variables you want and add some functions too like my translate function.

```
function myCube(size,pos){
    this.obj = cube({size:size,center:false}).translate(pos);
    this.size = size;
    this.pos = pos;
    this.translate = function(pos){
        this.obj.translate(pos);
    };
}
```

then you can make a cube like this `var MC = new myCube(radius, [x,y,z]);`

and now to get your radius you can do `MC.size;`

it does get tricky when you try to do something with the shape itself, you'll have to do something like `union(MC.obj, CIL.obj)`

*ps: I hope this helps although I know this isn't the ideal way and there's probably some easy way of doing it but this worked for me.*